# How does RESW in SIC machine works

Tags: assembly, instruction-set, microprocessors, sic

This is instructions set give in the standard text of System program
( Leland L Beck )for transferring data 5 from accumulator to memory

As you all know SIC is a hypothetical machine

```
LDA   FIVE   Load character 5 into register A
STA ALPHA    Store in Alpha
LDCH CHARZ      Load Character Z into A
STCH C1        Store in character variable  C1
.
.
.   
ALPHA RESW 1    One Word Variable
FIVE WORD 5     One-Word Constant
CHAR BYTE C 'Z' One Byte Constant
C1 RESB 1        One Byte Variable
```

I am confused in the statement on how this instruction

**ALPHA RESW 1**

is being handle

Can you explain to me or give a detailed reference or answer  to help me understand how RESW is processed by the assembler and how does it get reflected while converting this mnemonic codes to object code and how they gets loaded ..and linked and all ..

and how it is being process at the micro instruction level of the processor

I am an amateur in this system programming domain and any answer would be highly appreciable with great respect

Comment: It works the same as `WORD` except you don't provide an initial value so it can be anything.  It's only used during assembly and linking, the cpu never sees it. It's not an instruction. On systems where you have a section for uninitialized data (e.g. `.bss`) you can use this method to avoid enlarging the binary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is too broad to give great detail to every topic of going from textual programming language to running program with memory, so here's a brief overview.

All programming languages need to be able to support data declarations, for global variables, for string literals, floating point constants, etc.., however, only the assembler/compiler reads data declarations, the processor doesn't read data declarations.

The assembler reads each data declaration and reserves some space in the executable program file for that declaration (modulo `.bss`, wherein only a count is increased within the program file).  The data declarations will later become memory in the process of the running program.

Each data declarations has one or more memory addresses, and the associated label, when present, is equated with the lowest of those addresses.

Each time an instruction or data declaration is read by the assembler, it accumulates a machine code instruction or data item, appending to the associated section of current content in the object or executable file (which could be shared code & data or separated code & data).  As it does that, it increments an internal location counter that tells it what the next available memory address will be.  On some systems it knows the absolute address of things it is placing in memory, and on other systems it knows only an offset from the beginning.

On systems that use a linker, it will combine like sections of object code together,  and also resolve cross references, with the final output being an executable program file.

> how this instruction `ALPHA RESW 1` is being handle

For all practical purposes this specific instruction is the same as `ALPHA WORD 0`.  The difference with `RESW` is a value larger than 1 can be used as an easy way to create an initially zero buffer or array.

A label can be referred to by other data declarations and by processor instructions.

The assembler will translate a reference to a label within a processor instruction into an [addressing mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addressing_mode), which is an encoding of how the processor can reach/access that address at runtime.  An addressing mode will usually specify some immediate value to identify the desired memory location.  When the processor executes such an instruction, it will perform the address calculation according to the addressing mode in order to read or write the memory at the label (or capture the address of the label, or branch to the label).

When the executable program file gets loaded into memory, the machine code instructions are loaded into memory, as is the space and initial values for the declared data, and this is how the actual storage comes into being.

Comment: Loved your beautiful explanation really owes a great thanks and respect  for you ..for spending your valuable time ,energy and resource to help me like this ..I have a great respect for you ..thanks a lot